# Call fails on Windows Phone 7, but works on Windows and Xbox 360

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, windows-phone-7.1, xna-4.0

So, I'm having a weird issue here.  I am using the same XNA code across Windows, Xbox 360 and Windows Phone 7.  I can get most of it to work, but when Level tries to call TileMap on the Windows Phone 7 version, it never reaches TileMap.  However, on Windows and Xbox 360, it works just fine.  Is there something extra I have to do here?

A few more details.  On the Windows Phone version I am getting a "Could not evaluate expression" message from the debugger for certain values.  This does not happen on the Windows version.  As well, if I let it continue on long enough, I get a OutOfMemoryException, even though the image I'm calling in is about a KB in size, and the .map file would create only a 3x3 matrix.

GameplayScreen.cs

```
    private Level level;
    ...
    public override void LoadContent()
    {
        if (Content == null)
            Content = new ContentManager(ScreenManager.Game.Services, "Content");
        //Create Sprite Batch for drawing textures
        //spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        //Load fonts
        hudFont = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("Fonts/hud");

        lifeIcon = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Sprites/Player/lifeIco");

        //Load overlays
        //winOverlay = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Overlays/win");
        //loseOverlay = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Overlays/lose");

        try
        {
            MediaPlayer.IsRepeating = true;
            MediaPlayer.Play(Content.Load<Song>("Sounds/music"));
        }
        catch { }

        LoadNextLevel();

        //Camera.InitializeScreen(graphics);

        base.LoadContent();
    } //end LoadContent

    /// <summary>
    /// Loads the next level.
    /// </summary>
    public void LoadNextLevel()
    {
        //Set the next level
        levelIndex = (levelIndex + 1) % numberOfLevels;

        if (level != null)
            level.Dispose();

        level = new Level(ScreenManager.Game.Services, levelIndex);

    } //end LoadNextLevel()
```

Level.cs

```
    private TileMap levelMap;
    public Level(IServiceProvider service, int levelIndex)
    {
        //Create content manager for current level.
        content = new ContentManager(service, "Content");

        //Load level map
        //This is where the code hangs
        levelMap = new TileMap(this, levelIndex, content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Tiles/tiles"));


        //Load sounds
        //exampleSound = content.Load<SoundEffect>("Sounds/example");

        //Initialize Camera
        Camera.InitializeLevel(levelMap);
        player = new Player(this, start);
    } //end Level
```

TileMap.cs

```
    public TileMap(Level level, int levelIndex, Texture2D tileSheet)
    {
        // Never reaches here on Windows Phone 7 Version
        // Comes right here on Windows and Xbox 360 Version
        this.tileSheet = tileSheet;

        string levelPath = string.Format("Content/Levels/{0}.map", levelIndex);
```

A few things I have already been suggest and tried to do:

I have tried to call "Tiles/tiles" outside of the call to Tile Map and I have tried to compress tiles with DXT compression.  The "Tiles/tiles" loads up perfectly fine but the call still fails and I still get the OutOfMemoryException. The total file size of my contents is 1.23 MB.

Comment: I don't know much about WP7, but based on your description I don't think your texture size is what's hurting you, here.  If you call `GC.GetTotalMemory()` before creating a `TileMap`, how much memory is being consumed?  And how big is the `TileMap` class in memory?  Posting a more complete version of `TileMap` may be useful.

Comment: When evaluating expressions (In the "Watch" window, for example) in Visual Studio, the command is executed, in this case, on the target platform (assuming it's a phone or an emulator). This expression evaluation has a certain timeout, and so it fails to complete on time. Are you trying this on the real device or on the emulator? Also try running the same code without debugging, see if the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

At Level.cs, instead of passing the content as a service, pass all your things loaded prehand: {Texture2D, Sound}. 
In XNA you usually have all the Content loaded in the main Game Class or component. I am 95% this is the cause of the "Could not evaluate expression".

Also, take a look at the .NET Compact Framework 2.0 and see how the Garbage Collector works:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stevenpr/archive/2004/07/26/197254.aspx